# How to change the size of my app, so that it will fit to every smartphone? Android studio

Tags: android, size

[image]

How to change the size of my app, so that it will fit to every smartphone? Android studio

I don't know how to ask the question correctly. I just installed Android 
studio today.

Comment: never set hard width/height's ie. your 90dp you have set and use match_parent

Comment: you need to make sure you width and height of the area isnt fixed. For example 100dp. You want to make sure you use match_parent. This will extend the background out. Can you show us your XML code?

Answer (score 0):

First off, Size doesn't decide whether it'll fit for an Android phone or not . It's decided by the API versions you use to compile and the way you've made your app suitable for being run on different devices.

If you're looking for dividing your app as different apks try https://mindorks.com/blog/how-to-create-multiple-apk-files-for-android-application

Comment: hes not talking about the size of the application, but the size of the content inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using fixed height/width , because different phones have different sizes.

You can use either Linear Layout and set the attribute layout weight
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Or you can use Relative Layout to position views
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html